# How to combine dups from dictionary with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need some help with parsing some database records with Python3.  First I do not have access or permission to change the query behind this process, so I cant change the recordset. By looking at the recordset, it might be safe to say that there is a one to many relationship behind the scenes. I have a list of dictionaries like below

```
(
 {'FirstName': 'Steve', 'LastName': 'Smith': 'Field3': 'A'},
 {'FirstName': 'Steve', 'LastName': 'Smith': 'Field3': 'B'},
 {'FirstName': 'Steve', 'LastName': 'Smith': 'Field3': 'C'},
)
```

I would like to combine the field3 values into one comma separated string value and remove the duplicate records.

The outcome I'm trying to get is
{'FirstName': 'Steve', 'LastName': 'Smith', 'Field3': 'A, B, C'}

I hope you great people on stack can help!  Thanks!!

Comment: The duplicate obviously performs the combinations in a different way, but your case is simpler; no nested `dict`s and instead of `sum`ing `Fraction`s, you can just use `', '.join` to combine the `list`s of your `Field3` values. If you can't use the reasoning from the dupe to solve your problem, feel free to post a [MCVE] of the code you can't get working, but don't ask for us to write it for you from scratch please.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ShadowRanger!   You don't want to do my work for me huh? ;)  I will look into using join.